# Mensaje que pregunte si estoy seguro de esta accion en html y php

Tags: php, html

llevo rato investigando en este foro y en otros, y no logro dar con la forma de que en el presente listado con el que estoy trabajando, pueda borrar el registro, pero que antes pregunte si estoy seguro. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
echo "<script>
    function Borrar()
    {
       confirm('Estas Seguro que deseas Borrar este Registro?');
    }
</script>";
```

Luego donde llamo a la funcion:

```
echo "<td align='center' class='borrar'><a onclick='Borrar()' href='borrar_estudiante.php?id=$estudiante[cedula]'><img src='../imagen/delete.png'></a></td>";
```

El mensaje aparece bien, pero si le doy cancelar igual pasa a la siguiente pagina, habiendo borrado ese registro. Osea si el doy aceptar o cancelar hara lo mismo.

He probado otras funciones y si no ocurre esto, entonces ni siquiera parece el mensaje.

Es algo simple de hacer, pero espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberia ser algo como:

```
echo "<script>
function Borrar()
{
   if(confirm('Estas Seguro que deseas Borrar este Registro?')){
    return true;
   }
   else{
    return false;
   }
}
</script>";
```

Esto por que el confirm te retorna **true** cuando aceptas o **false** cuando cancelas

EDIT: El enlace debe estar de la siguiente forma

```
echo "<td align='center' class='borrar'><a onclick='return Borrar();' href='borrar_estudiante.php?id=$estudiante[cedula]'><img src='../imagen/delete.png'></a></td>";
```

Aca el ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/23qa43zt/7/

Comment: Persiste el problema. Hasta probe tecleando escape cuando sale el mensaje para evitar la accion e igualmente la realiza y elimina el mensaje.

Comment: Disculpa, olvide agregar el return en el a, edite la respuesta

Comment: Excelente, ahora si. Muchas gracias!! Se aprendió algo nuevo hoy.